# Pylance doesn't recognize built-in python functions

Tags: python, visual-studio, function, pylance

My cat ran over my keyboard,now Pylance is not recognizing built-in functions like print, hex, len, and input and it marks then undefined. Also in my Django project, some imports of classes started to be underlined, but they continue to work. All the brackets are highlighted in yellow, they definitely weren't highlighted in yellow before. You can see what it looks like here https://i.stack.imgur.com/2gfhZ.jpg.

Sorry for a bit stupid explanation of the problem, I'm facing this for the first time and have no idea what to do.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a problem where none of the Python built-ins were being resolved in Visual Studio Code.
I was seeing various Pylance errors, such as `PylancereportUndefinedVariable` for built-in functions and types. For example: `"print" is not defined (PylancereportUndefinedVariable)`.

I tried several different solutions, including experimenting with different versions of Pylance and completely reinstalling VSCode, but none of them worked.

Configuring the `python.analysis.stubPath` in the user settings.json file resolved the issue for me.

```json
{
    "python.analysis.stubPath": "~/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.vscode-pylance-2023.12.1/dist/typeshed-fallback/stdlib/"
}
```

Details:

- Visual Studio Code Version: 1.85.1
- Pylance Version: v2023.12.1

Answer (score 0):

**Did you save the file?** If that didn't help then you need to know that in Python you can create local variables that overshadow built-in functions:

```py
def myprint():
    pass

# built-in print is no longer usable here
print = myprintj
```

I am sorry if it will not help, try to explain the problem better next time.

Comment: I clicked crtl + left mouse button on the function and I opened a file where were many functions. After the cat ran, file was deleted, maybe this is the reason?How can i open this file with functions again?

Comment: 1. Most likely you opened the file with built-in functions; you can't edit them and you shouldn't.
2. If that's right, then congratulations - VSCode is able to recognize functions as you wanted.
3. If you want to see the functions definition again, then repeat what you did. Open whatever .py file, type your functions, <CTRL+Left Click> on the function or <CTRL+ Right Click> + "Show function definition".